# Add a triangular point to a div that changes with the content height with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have a div and I need to give it an angular point. The height will vary based on its content so using pseudo content and borders like in the article below wont work.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

[image]

As this is a progressive enhancement I only need to support modern browsers.

Comment: Will the square itself decide the height or the content to the right of the triangle? Is it acceptable to change the html or are you really looking for a pure css solution? I think I have an idea how this can be solved using inline svg, but at the moment I'm pretty busy. If there's not a solution in a few hours I can give it a try.

Comment: The height is decided by the content.

Comment: @Paulie_D not a duplicate, a link to how it works is even right in the question. And explanation why it wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: Noted...I misread. - Retracted.

Comment: Could someone explain the down vote?

Comment: not exactly right, but could be interesting [for you](http://paweldebik.com/blog/dynamic-css-3-shapes/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternate answer, using gradients and pseudo elements

```css
#one {height: 100px;}
#two {height: 200px;}
.corner {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.corner:after, .corner:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 50%;
}
.corner:before {
    top: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, green 50%, transparent 51%);
}
.corner:after {
    bottom: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, green 50%, transparent 51%);
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="corner"></div>
<div id="two" class="corner"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You could do this using `svg`.

`svg`'s(background) `height` totally depends on `#content`'s(text) `height`.

[image]

<kbd>**[Demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/YPNZNB)**</kbd>

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
  word-break: break-all;
  width: 110px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg id="bg" width="150" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 150 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0,0 h110 l40,50 l-40,50 h-110z" fill="#6ED901" />
  </svg>
  <div id="content">This content is dynamic and the height of the triangle will change with the height of the content. The width is fixed. Try adding some more text and see the height change. Also, notice the padding.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can get rid of that javascript, just give your #bg a height of 100%.

Comment: @mmgross - I can't believe I forgot that, thanks for reminding

Answer (score 3):

### CSS clip-path

This uses `clip-path` property, which is not supported by many modern browsers.

```css
#one {
  width: 300px;
  background-color:#6ED901;
  padding:10px;
  word-break: break-all;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

span{
  width:240px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"><span>Dynamic. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</span></div>
```

### CSS - Gradients

Browser support for CSS gradients is fairly good. Please note that this is essentially the same as **Vals'** answer, but just with a dynamic height.

```css
.shape {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #6ED901;
    position: relative;
    word-break:break-all;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}
.shape:after, .shape:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50%;
}
.shape:before {
    top: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, #6ED901 50%, transparent 51%);
}
.shape:after {
    bottom: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #6ED901 50%, transparent 51%);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi "Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi "Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi "Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi "Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi "Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi</div>
```

### CSS + JS

The following solution uses CSS and JS and works cross-browser. The JS was provided by **web-tiki.**

```js
var height = document.getElementById('one').offsetHeight/2;
document.getElementById('two').style.borderTopWidth = height + 'px';
document.getElementById('two').style.borderBottomWidth = height + 'px';
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#one{
    width:200px;
    background-color:#6ED901;
    display:block;
    word-break: break-all;
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
}
#two{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    left: 220px;
    width:0px;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-right-width:0;
    border-left-width:80px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #6ED901;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="one"> ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg ghjg</div>
  <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: here is a simple jQuery script that calculates the height of `#one` and sets the borders to `#two` accordingly http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ge43sLg8/

Comment: Thanks a ton @web-tiki! Actually I don't know javascript. I'll edit the post with proper credits.

Answer (score 2):

I would try with SVG in the background:

```
div {
    background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 80 100"><rect x="-5" y="-5" width="90" height="110" fill="#fff" /><polygon fill="green" points="0,0 80,50 0,100"/></svg>');
    background-position:100% 50%;
    background-size:auto 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wm1am7ry/

Note: the SVG image has a white background rectangle and a green triangle. So it won't work if the background under arrow isn't a solid color.

If the width was fixed you could put the SVG to a generated content positioned outside the green box which would make it possible to avoid white background under the arrow:

http://jsfiddle.net/wm1am7ry/1/

```
div {
    background-color:green;
    padding:20px;
    margin:10px 0;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
}
div::after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:100%;
    width:100%;
        background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 80 100"><polygon fill="green" points="0,0 80,50 0,100"/></svg>');
    background-position:0 50%;
    background-size:auto 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done by using skew and rotate

```css
.cont {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.arrow {
  background: #6ED901;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
.arrow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background: #6ED901;
  top: 0;
  transform: skew(14deg, 19deg) rotate(43deg);
  transform-origin: right;
  z-index: -1;
  right: 0;
}
.cont {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="arrow">. Proin faucibus arcu quis ante.Proin faucibus arcu quis ante.Proin faucibus arcu quis ante.Proin faucibus arcu quis ante. Proin faucibus arcu quis ante.</div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="arrow">Proin faucibus arcu quis ante.Proin faucibus arcu.Proin faucibus arcu quis ante.Proin faucibus arcu.</div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="arrow">Proin faucibus arcu quis ante.Proin faucibus arcu.</div>
</div>
```